# Fb Prophet Model Plot : NoneType object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nonetype, facebook-prophet

I am not able to plot anything in Prophet model when I use the commands such as:

```
plot1 = m.plot(forecast)
plt2 = m.plot_components(forecast)
```

I am getting error

> NoneType object is not subscriptable

[image: Screenshot of my error]

Comment: Please provide code for model training

Answer (score 1):

You did not train your model,  here is how we can reproduce the error :

```py
import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet
from prophet.plot import plot_plotly


m = Prophet()

# for testing
forecast = pd.DataFrame()

plot_plotly(m, forecast)
```

To correct that you need to train the model using `m.fit(your_data)`.

Please check the [Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api) it contain detailed steps.